# Adding descendents to xdocument root element issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a set of descendent nodes I want to add from one xml into the root element of another xml, but in doing this, rather than getting a structured xml file, when I open the document, I get a big lump of long lines with the descendents of the original document.

Is there a way to add the descendent nodes of one document into the root element of another document?

My code is like so:

```
foreach (var v in doc.Descendants())
{
    if (v.Name.LocalName == "NOSDocument")
    {
        doc2.Root.Add(doc.DescendantNodes());
    }
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, you're trying to flatten the xml file?

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you're expecting to get and what you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy all the nodes from one document to another you can do it this way:

```
XElement doc1 = XElement.Load("doc1_file.xml");
XElement doc2 = new XElement("doc2");

foreach(XElement child in doc1.Elements())
    doc2.Add(child);
```

Comment: But need to put it in the root element?

Comment: doc2 is the root element, otherwise explain your question better.